# Creating instance of Dropbox.API in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropbox-api

I'm migrating a project in MVC into the equivalent in ASP.net Core, I need to get access to some files in Dropbox, I've configure my project in ASP.net Core with Dropbox.Api, because it seems that DropNet is not supported in ASP.net Core(when I try to install it I get the following error message: `The dependency DropNet 1.10.23 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.`) If you know any way that I could use DropNet let me know.

So I've installed Dropbox.Api and I've created my own app and I can get access to it using a Dropbox client object:

```
 DropboxClient client = new DropboxClient("cU5M-a4exaAAAAAAAAABDVZsKsdfsd2343slOeFEo-HByusdgsgsgsf33FyOXH");
```

But when I'm trying to connect to the Dropbox MVC account it was used DropNet, and the configuration is different(no generated access token in there):

```
 _client = new DropNetClient("gwie23zapdfddsswt8", "64545ghdfhjcf", userToken: "wdggff662sd4", userSecret: "234564fthhyqo");
```

I have some questions about it:

1- No way that I can install in ASP.net Core the DropNet package that was used in previous framework versions?

2-I've been following [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial) tutorial, in there they only talk about the `Generated access token` they don't talk about `userToken` and `userSecret`, in the MVC project it was used DropNet they used those parameters to create a Dropbox client. And in the tutorial that I referenced above they just create that client like this:

`DropboxClient client = new DropboxClient("cU5M-a4exaAAAAAAAAABDVZsKsdfsd2343slOeFEo-HByusdgsgsgsf33FyOXH");`

Is there anyway that I can create that instance using Dropbox.API using `userToken` and `userSecret`? DropboxClient only accept two parameters: the generated access token and an instance of DropboxClientConfig.

3- Once deployed my application in ASP.net Core would be possible for every user to download files using the client that I created behind the scenes:

```
DropboxClient client = new DropboxClient("cU5M-a4exaAAAAAAAAABDVZsKsdfsd2343slOeFEo-HByusdgsgsgsf33FyOXH");
```

Comment: Are you wanting to run on the full .NET Framework, or on the cross platform .NET Core? (ASP.NET Core can run on either)

Comment: @mason I'm using the full .NET Framework

Comment: Are you sure? Your error message seems to indicate otherwise: "NETCoreApp". Check your project.json.

Comment: @mason I think you are right, according to my project.json this is what it contains:  `"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },` Could I change this to use the full .NET Framework instead and then install DropNet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [NuGet package of Dropbox.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dropbox.Api/), you can see that it targets `DNXCore 5.0` in the PCL package. Which is compatible with .NET Core. Using an `imports` statement we can tell NuGet that we are compatible with DNX Core 5.0 and want their packages to restore:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Dropbox.Api": "3.6.0"
},
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
```

Notice the `"imports": "dnxcore50"` statement.

---

If you want to use full .NET, you'll have to change your project.json file to something like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Dropbox.Api": "3.6.0"
},
"frameworks": {
  "net46": { }
}
```

Where `net46` can be any .NET framework you want to target.